# In a 3D grid of cubes, how to calculate index of a cube if we only know it's coordinates and the way cubes are generated?

Tags: 3d, vector

I have a code that generates a grid of equally sized cubes in a cubic volume of given limited size, intended to be used for 3d path finding. Let's say cubes are objects stored in an array called `Grid[]`. I need to mathematically retrieve an index of the cube in that array, when knowing only it's X, Y and Z coordinates.

As an example, imagine a volume that can fit 6 cubes in length (**X**), 4 cubes in width (**Y**), and 3 cubes in height (**Z**). That's a total of 72 cubes. That means every cube has it's unique X, Y and Z coordinates; `{0, 0, 0}` for the first cube (`Grid[0]`), all the way to the `{5, 3, 2}` for the last cube (`Grid[71]`).

The cubes are generated by filling the Z axis upwards, than the Y axis, and lastly the X. Here's a drawing to explain it better:

[image]

**What mathematical formula can I use to calculate the *i* by using cube's X, Y and Z coordinates, and the volume's maximum X, Y and Z values?**

I am not allowed to have a separate HashMap to look through it. I am also not supposed to loop through all of the array members and compare the stored values with the given coordinates - the grid could contain millions of cubes.

Comment: The phrases "not allowed to" & "not supposed to" suggest that this might be homework. If that's the case, it is okay to ask about homework, but you should acknowledge that in your question text & you can review our other homework guideline [here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2659/33287).

Comment: @Pikalek it's not homework, it just needs to be as optimized as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a geometric progression. Here's a working formula:

```
i = z + y * maxZ + x * maxY * maxZ
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = z + y * CubesPerColumn + x * CubesPerSlice
```

In your diagram,

```
CubesPerColumn = 3
```

and

```
CubesPerSlice = CubesPerColumn * ColumnsPerSlice = 3 * 4 = 12
```